# Selecting nth child in selenium

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath, phpunit

At first my question was about why I get "Element //table[2] not found" error while selecting the second of 2 tables. Xpaths that didn't work (using *assertElementPresent* function):

```
//table[2]
(//table)[2] (here I got error for wrong xpath)
//table[position()=2]
//table[last()] (here I got the first table)
```

But finally I've found the answer

```
$this->assertElementPresent("xpath=(//table)[2]");
```

So now my question is why does the last statement work while others not? And why

```
$this->assertElementPresent("//table[1]");
```

works as it is whitout *xpath=...*?

PHP 5.5.7, PHPUnit 3.8, Selenium 2.37.0, MacOS 10.9.1

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of each of your expressions:

```
//table[2]
```

Select all table elements that are the 2nd table element child of their respective parent.

```
(//table)[2]
```

Select the second item from the set of all table elements (this is what you are trying to do).

```
//table[position()=2]
```

Same as the first one. `[number]` is shorthand for `[position() = number]`

```
//table[last()]
```

Select all table elements that are the last table element child of their respective parent.

Regarding your second question, from the [Selenium documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html):

> > Without an explicit locator prefix, Selenium uses the following default strategies:
> >          •dom, for locators starting with "document."
> >          •xpath, for locators starting with "//"
> >          •identifier, otherwise

`(//table)[2]` does not start with `//`, and that is why the expression was not accepted without `xpath=`.